# Card Deck Ordering

Tags: python

I need to be able to sort the deck after it's shuffled. My thought is to break the list back into it's two components, and check if each component is in order, then put it back together.

**How can I access the value portion and suit portion separately from inside the Deck class?**

If you have a better idea of how to do this, I would also appreciate that.

the `.sort()` call will not work due to a the items in the list being a char + int i.e ('2C', 'KH').

```
import random

class Card:

    def __init__(self, suit, order):
        self.order = order
        self.suit = suit

    def fan(self):
        print(self.order, "of", self.suit)

class Deck():

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']:
            for order in ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit, order))

    def fan(self):
        for c in self.deck:
            c.fan()

    def shuffle(self):
        for suit in ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']:
            for order in ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit, order))
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        return self.deck.pop()

    def isOrdered(self):
        pass

    def Order(self):
        pass
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Sorting the deck? What means "mixed-type entry"? To allow sorting of cards you should define comparation operators for it (`__gt__`, `__lt__`, ...) or calculate a key value for each card (mainly `<suit index> * 13 + <order index>`) and use this calculation function as key function in `sort()`

Comment: The items in the `Deck.deck` list are `Card` objects. Or do you mean a different list?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I want the `card` objects ordered in the `deck` list. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, I have created an answer.

Comment: Given that a deck of cards is a fixed set, it would probably be faster to just recreate a sorted deck than to sort a scrambled one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Teach" the card objects how to compare to each other:

The `sort()` method requires that card objects must be able to at least "answer" the question `card1 < card2` so the `Card` class needs an additional method:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    """
    Returns self < other
    """

    # Following two should better be defined globally (outside of method
    # and maybe outside of the Card class

    SUIT_LIST = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    ORDER_LIST = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

    if self.suit == other.suit:
        return ORDER_LIST.index(self.order) < ORDER_LIST.index(other.order)
    else:
        return SUIT_LIST.index(self.suit) < SUIT_LIST.index(other.suit)
```

Now card objects can be compared with `<` and a list of card objects can be sorted.

Comment: You don't need the `index` method for `SUIT_LIST`; the four suits are already in alphabetical order.

Comment: @chepner Right, but this is more generic in case a different suit order is desired later.